# gulpをインストールするとサンプルコードが使えない

Tags: macos, node.js

以下のURLの「サンプルの構築と実行」の手順を進めていますが、`npm install` コマンドがエラーとなり完了できません。sudo を付けて実行してみましたが変わりませんでした。
解消方法を教えていただけますでしょうか。

https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/microsoftteams/platform/tutorials/get-started-nodejs-app-studio

OSはmacのver10.15.3です。

以下、ターミナルに表示されるエラー内容です。

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall stat
npm ERR! path /Users/xxx/msteams-samples-hello-world-nodejs/node_modules/botbuilder-teams/node_modules/botbuilder/skills-validator/skills-validator-1.0.0.tgz
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/xxx/msteams-samples-hello-world-nodejs/node_modules/botbuilder-teams/node_modules/botbuilder/skills-validator/skills-validator-1.0.0.tgz'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

Answer (score 0):

今回使っているコードのリポジトリに、同様のエラーに関する issue が立っていました: https://github.com/OfficeDev/msteams-samples-hello-world-nodejs/issues/33

ちゃんと中身を精査していませんが、どうも依存関係絡みの問題なようです。`package-lock.json` を削除したらインストールできたという旨のコメントがついており、とすると何かしら依存ライブラリに非互換な変更が入ってしまったのかもしれません。（package-lock.json を消して再インストールしてしまうとチュートリアルで想定されているのとは違うバージョンのライブラリが入ってしまう可能性があるのですぐにはオススメできませんが、参考まで。）

Comment: ご回答、共有ありがとうございました。上記も実施してみたのですがダメでした。

Comment: 出力されたエラーメッセージも同じでしたか？

Comment: 前回はできなかったのですが、再度ディレクトリを削除して再度ダウンロード後にpackage-lock.jsonファイルを除去して実行したところ完了できました。ありがとうございます。その後の手順の「npm start」コマンドは「package.json」が無いってエラーが出ており、内部で使われているコマンドが無いというエラーでしたので、まずは自身で調べてみようと思います。